# wix service dependencies

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.6

My product has several features including two services. Let's call them ServiceA and ServiceB. Both of these service features are optional. However if both ServiceA and ServiceB is selected during install I want to create a service dependency between them so that ServiceB will depend on ServiceA (in other words ServiceB must always start before ServiceA is launched).

How do I achieve this in WIX 3.6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<ServiceInstall Id="ServiceA" DisplayName="ServiceA" Name="ServiceA" 
    Account="LocalSystem" Start="auto" ErrorControl="normal" Type="ownProcess">
    <ServiceDependency Id="ServiceB"/>
</ServiceInstall>
```

That should work, check out [ServiceDependency documentation element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicedependency.html)